# Kafka Connect fails to deserialize offset every time

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

This is probably something obvious, however, I can't figure it out.

Each time I start my source connector it fails to read the offset stored in a file with the following error:

```
21:05:01:519 | ERROR | pool-1-thread-1 | o.a.k.c.s.OffsetStorageReaderImpl | CRITICAL: Failed to deserialize offset data when getting offsets for tas
k with namespace zohocrm-source-calls. No value for this data will be returned, which may break the task or cause it to skip some data. This could ei
ther be due to an error in the connector implementation or incompatible schema.
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additiona
l fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:309)
```

Here are my StandaloneConfig values:

```
    access.control.allow.methods =
    access.control.allow.origin =
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    internal.key.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.value.converter = class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    key.converter = class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
    offset.flush.interval.ms = 60000
    offset.flush.timeout.ms = 5000
    offset.storage.file.filename = maxoptra-data.offset
    rest.advertised.host.name = null
    rest.advertised.port = null
    rest.host.name = null
    rest.port = 8083
    task.shutdown.graceful.timeout.ms = 5000
    value.converter = class io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
```

Here is my connector config:

```
    connector.class = com.maxoptra.data.zoho.connect.ZohoCrmSourceConnector
    key.converter = null
    name = zohocrm-source-calls
    tasks.max = 1
    transforms = null
    value.converter = null
```

Please advise.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Set `key.converter.schemas.enable=true` and `value.converter.schemas.enable=true`. This will make the JsonConverter try to interpret your schema instead of deserializing the default schema that doesn't match what you have here

Answer (score 0):

The Kafka Connect Avro Converter integrates with Schema Registry to convert data for Kafka Connect to and from Avro format. Since you are using AvroConverter for value and key, you have to set the url for respective Schema Registry.

```
key.converter.schema.registry.url

value.converter.schema.registry.url
```